# Remove element from an ArrayList after getting it

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have a method that takes the first element of an ArrayList and puts it into another ArrayList.

Let's say that A = {1, 2, 3} and C = {}

After the method getStudent() my lists now look like this:

A = {1, 2, 3} and C = {1}

Is there a way, using ArrayLists, to have the 1 disappear from list A as soon as it is passed to C?

My code:

```
public Disk getStudent() {

// so it gives me element 0
    Student topStudent = studentCollection.get(studentCollection.size() - studentCollection.size());
    return topStudent;
}
```

I know you can do something like this with stack, but I need this particular piece to be an ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

In place of `get`, use [`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-).

Also, note that by subtracting the collection's size from itself, you're getting 0, so it's simpler to write the following:

```
studentCollection.remove(0);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.

Comment: @Ahm:  You're welcome.  Since you seem to be new around these parts, [this is what you should do](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when someone answers your question satisfactorily instead of saying "Thanks" in a comment.  But you're still welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Does it happen linearly? If so, you could use a stack or a queue and pop or dequeue respectively and and then add the result to the new list. Otherwise, you'll want to have three operations - store the value from studentCollection, remove it from studentCollection and then add the value to the new list.

Answer (score 0):

if your function return an object, you can use it to remove the element from the ArrayList

```
yourArrayList.remove(getStudent());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to achieve this

1. Use `List.remove(0)` to delete the element after fetching it and adding it to another list.
2. Use `queue` instead of `list` for the lists. that way you can do something like -  `C.add(A.poll())`

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom get method in which remove element from the list before returning.

For example:

```
public Student getFrstStudentFromList(){
    if(studentCollection.size()!=0){
        Student topStudent = studentCollection.get(0);
        studentCollection.remove(topStudent); // or studentCollection.remove(0);
        return topStudent;
    }
    return null;
}
```

another way

```
ArrayList<Student> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Student> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(new Student("Student 1"));
list1.add(new Student("Student 2"));
list1.add(new Student("Student 3"));

moveFrstElementFromList1ToList2(list1,list2);

public static void moveFrstElementFromList1ToList2(ArrayList<Student> l1, ArrayList<Student> l2){
    if(l1.size()!=0){
        l2.add(l1.get(0));
        l1.remove(0);
    }
}
```

I hope this may help you